# Why I cant use Get-QADComputer inside a job?

Tags: powershell, jobs, powershell-3.0, quest

why the Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement is not available inside a job ?

Ok when running interractively :

```
PS>Get-QADComputer -SearchRoot '$ou' -SizeLimit 200 |
    %{ if (Test-Connection -Quiet $_.name) { 
         $lastboottime = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $_.name).LastBootUpTime;  
         $sysuptime = (Get-Date) - System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($lastboottime)
write-host "$($_.name) allumé depuis $($sysuptime.days) jours" }  }

domain\comp1$ allumé depuis 8 jours
domain\comp2$ allumé depuis 0 jours
```

But when using job :

```
PS>start-job -Name uptime -ScriptBlock{Get-QADComputer -SearchRoot '$ou' -SizeLimit 200 |
        %{ if (Test-Connection -Quiet $_.name) { 
             $lastboottime = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $_.name).LastBootUpTime;  
             $sysuptime = (Get-Date) - System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($lastboottime)
    write-host "$($_.name) allumé depuis $($sysuptime.days) jours" }  }}
```

it complains to not find the command

```
PS>Receive-Job uptime -Keep
Le terme «Get-QADComputer» n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande,
fonction, fichier de script ou programme exécutable. Vérifiez l'orthographe du
nom, ou si un chemin d'accès existe, vérifiez que le chemin d'accès est correct et
réessayez.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-QADComputer:String) [], Command
   NotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell jobs run in a seperate process, so try importing the module first in your scriptblock. Ex:

```
Start-Job -InitializationScript { Import-Module ...module here... } -Name uptime -ScriptBlock { ...your code.... }
```

Comment: good point, just added ` Add-PSSnapin -name Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement` on top of scriptblock

Comment: isnt PS V3 supposed to autoload module when needed ? maybe this mechanism doesnt work with snapins

Comment: Snapins are different from modules. PS3.0 auto-loads modules from the locations stored in `$env:PSModulePath`

Comment: Yeah snapins are obsolete v1 tech and won't autoload